# ${\left| {\sum\limits_{i =1}^n {{{\left( {\frac{{{x_i}}}{{{x_1}}}} \right)}^m}} } \right|^{\frac{1}{m}}}\mathop \to \limits^? 0$

Tags: calculus

Let ${x_1} = \max \{ {x_i}:i = 1,2,...,n\} $

Is it true that

$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to \infty } {\left| {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{{\left( {\frac{{{x_i}}}{{{x_1}}}} \right)}^m}} } \right|^{\frac{1}{m}}} \to 0$

Comment: I think you can use the fact that $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}||x||_p=||x||_{\infty}$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space.

Comment: Ah, that expression looks familiar. However, be careful with nonpositive $x_1$s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  Provided all numbers are positive:
Depending on whether you start from $i=2$ (in the title) or $i=1$ (in the question), the effect of the $m$ is to remove all but the largest term,
so it is either $1$ or $x_2/x_1$.